# Setting Dynamic path name for input fields in Spring Form Tags

Tags: spring

I am trying to set the path name dynamically by using spring form tags based on the count value in jsp page. I tried to set the path like this

```
<form:select path = "relatives[<%=count%>].student.year.id"class="SiblingYear">
```

but it is showing error java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "<%=count%>"

Below is the full code :

```
<%int count=0;
 %>
   <tr align="center" id="dvtext1">
                <td>
                   <form:select path = "relatives[<%=count%>].student.year.id"  class="SiblingYear">
   <form:option value = "-1" label = "Select Year"/>
   <form:options items = "${student.years}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" />
</form:select>
```

If the value of count is zero I want the path name as `relatives[0].student.year.id`

can anyone help on this ??

Comment: can anyone assist how to achieve this?

Comment: I see no such string `<%=count%>` here

Comment: I tried to use scriptlet <%=count%> but that also not working

Comment: Are you using jsp with Spring?

Comment: The error you are getting is because <%=count%> will by default be String which obviously can't be used for array index.

Comment: Yes im using jsp with Spring, But I have tried like this also relatives["+count+"].student.year.id but still error showing Unterminated &lt;form:select tag

Answer (score 0):

This can be acheived through using JSTL Core library.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" %>
```

---

```
<%int count=0;%>
<c:set value="<%=count%>" var="countindex" />
<form:select path = "relatives[${countindex}].student.year.id"  class="SiblingYear">
```

---

As a whole example:

```
<%int count=0;%>
<c:set value="<%=count%>" var="countindex" />
<tr align="center" id="dvtext1">
  <td>
    <form:select path = "relatives[${countindex}].student.year.id"  class="SiblingYear">
      <form:option value = "-1" label = "Select Year"/>
      <form:options items = "${student.years}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" />
   </form:select>
```

---

For Reference:
https://developer.ucsd.edu/develop/user-interface-3/building-a-form/form-binding-with-collections.html